# Ionic - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I am using Ionic Framework version is 1.7.16

The line causing the error on Android is following

```
var obj = {[$myid] : firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP};
```

If i change the above line to following line then no error

```
var obj = {'test':'test'};
```

Ctrl Code:

```
.controller('SearchStateCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, $location, $stateParams, my_details) {
  $scope.stateId = $stateParams.stateId;
  $scope.my_details = my_details;

  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  $scope.my_id = user.uid;

  var database = firebase.database();
  var trips = database.ref('Trips/'+$stateParams.stateId);

  trips.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    $scope.my_trips = $firebaseArray(trips);
  }, function(err) {
     console.log("Something is wrong.");
  });

  $scope.addToMyTrip = function ($trip, $myid) {
    var tripRef = database.ref('MyTrips');
    var obj = {[$myid] : firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP};
    tripRef.set(obj).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Somthing went wrong.');
    });
    var tripRef = database.ref('MyTrips/'+$trip.$id);
    tripRef.set({
      'i-am': $trip['i-am'],
      'trip-date': $trip['trip-date'],
      'state-from': $trip['state-from'],
      'city-from': $trip['city-from'],
      'state-to': $trip['state-to'],
      'city-to': $trip['city-to'],
      'user-id': $trip['user-id']
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Somthing went wrong.');
    });
  }
})
```

Dynamic key name is for some reason giving error on android, everything is working fine when i am viewing it in the web page using

```
ionic serve --lab
```

[image: Error i am getting when i am deploying on android]

Comment: Post your complete code, then people can help.

Comment: seems like your controller is missing, could you post  the point where you use ng-ctrl and your controller definiton in js

Comment: Why do you have these square brackets around $myid ?  Have you tried var obj = {$myid : firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP};  ? (Notice: I don't know iconic)

Comment: without brackets i am getting following error:

**ionic.bundle.js:26794 Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument  contains an invalid key ($myid) in property 'Users.26ruYxpW6id5n1ZRnrmAGR161qU2.my-trips.-KNSSzyi9Je31934RlOj.requests-by'.  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"**
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30395:28)

Comment: Brackets are their for evaluating the value inside the bracket. To my understanding the problem is, when ionic tries to convert the code to android and ios it miss interprets this line for some reason. Because in the web view it is working fine.

Comment: Yeah, okay... frameworks are great, but don't ecxuse for syntax errors.  Maybe try this: var key = [$myid];
var obj = {};
obj[key] = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

Comment: Thanks Mr Emmanuel Delay, it worked. I really appreciate your help. Thanks for this valuable key information because i didn't knew i can pass a key like this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Emmanuel Delay the problem is solved by changing following line

```
var obj = {[$myid] : firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP};
```

to

```
var key = [$myid]; 
var obj = {}; 
obj[key] = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
```